# How can I reset the Pitch Bend function on my Axiom 25?

Tags: sound-design

How can I reset the Pitch Bend function on my [M-Audio - Axiom 25](http://www.m-audio.com/products/view/axiom-25#.Vu1qo5MrJBw) ????